# Failed to allocate a 27394783 byte allocation with 15063472 free bytes and 14MB until OOM exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception, out-of-memory

## Scenario

I am working on android application which downloads encrypted video file, save it in memory and then decrypt it when user click on play button of that file from the android application. And after decryption play that video.

## Problem

App works fine in most of the devices. But in Redmi note 4 (as per my testing on 3 different redmi note 4)it gives exception

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 27394783 byte allocation with 15063472 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
```

## Android Menifest.xml

```
    android:name=".receiver.ConnectivityListener"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

## In build.gradle

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries true
    dexInProcess = true
}
```

## logcat

```
2020-03-21 15:23:40.733 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 26MB allocation
2020-03-21 15:23:40.733 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-03-21 15:23:40.767 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 513MB to 512MB
2020-03-21 15:23:40.767 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 497MB/512MB, paused 435us total 33.194ms
2020-03-21 15:23:40.767 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 27394783 byte allocation with 15063472 free bytes and 14MB until OOM"


2020-03-21 15:23:40.778 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #9
Process: com.ehiddenbrain.prod, PID: 19593
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 27394783 byte allocation with 15063472 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1112)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
    at com.example.ehiddenbrain_v03.utility.Decoder.decryptVideo(Decoder.java:56)
    at com.example.ehiddenbrain_v03.background.DecoderBackgroundTask.doInBackground(DecoderBackgroundTask.java:66)
    at com.example.ehiddenbrain_v03.background.DecoderBackgroundTask.doInBackground(DecoderBackgroundTask.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
2020-03-21 15:23:40.779 19593-19699/com.ehiddenbrain.prod W/AndroidRuntime: finished raiseRlimit, rlim_cur:4096  rlim_max:4096
2020-03-21 15:23:40.945 19593-19696/com.ehiddenbrain.prod V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4696
2020-03-21 15:23:40.947 19593-19696/com.ehiddenbrain.prod V/FA: Activity paused, time: 240603587
```

If anyone know about this issue please help me ...
Thanks !!!

Comment: Well? It's saying it doesn't have enough memory.

Comment: yes sir with out of memory exception @chrylis-onstrike-

Comment: But memory is available in device. And then why it happens on 3 diffeerent redmi note 4 devices and not on others?? @user85421

Comment: How much total memory available do your redmi devices have? Is it more than the "15063472 free bytes" (15 MB) the error is listing?

Comment: 11.37 GB is free in internal memory. @RandallArms

Comment: Can we get an expanded logcat?

Comment: logcat added in question. @RandallArmsJr.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I change `ByteArrayOutputStream` (memory) by `FileOutputStrem` (disk). It works fine!

```kotlin
val fis = ByteArrayInputStream(fileData)
val cin = CipherInputStream(fis, cipher)
val fos = FileOutputStream(fileToSave)

val b = ByteArray(128)
var numberOfBytesRead: Int
while (cin.read(b).also { numberOfBytesRead = it } >= 0) {
    fos.write(b, 0, numberOfBytesRead)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering... But I am already using `FileOutputStrem`. If you have any other solution let me know. thanks @Victor